# Programmatically stop decreasing stock qty while placing an order in magento

Tags: magento

I would need to stop decreasing inventory while placing an order,
I need to do this activity only after successful payment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, We can disable this qty decrease pragmatically

**How ?**

Extend **Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage** and **Rewrite** the method **saveOrder**

**Changes**

before the following lines in the above method, will  be around #740 to #742

```
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote());
    $service->submitAll();
```

Add

```
    $quote = $this->getQuote();
    # Ref: Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::subtractQuoteInventory
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(true);
```

This will inform Magento that dont process inventory for the quote, so it wont decrease the qty even if it is configured to do so.

Comment: @Manaf PM,@Bijeesh K G This didn't worked for me....any other solution i am using authorize .net payment module and don't want to decrease quantity when payment failed...

Answer (score 5):

System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options

Decrease Stock When Order is Placed > No

Comment: definitely the simple way of doing it :)

Comment: Nice, thanks. Anyone know hot to then decrese qty only when a shipping is created? (so when a product go in processing status). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who want to find more information regarding subtraction on placing order, just need to study this event in both Magento EE/CE

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just disable stock management in the admin, unless there's a particular reason you need to do it this way?

You could setup an observer to add to the Qty after the succesful payment:
You can check here for a list of Magento events you can hook onto: http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento_events_cheat_sheet/

```
 <events>
   <sales_order_payment_pay>
      <observers>
        <my_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>my/observer</class>
            <method>addQty</method>
        </my_observer>
      </observers>
   </sales_order_payment_pay>     
</events>
```

And then your observer would add the Qty back on..

```
<?php
class Company_My_Model_Observer
{
    public function addQty($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getInvoice()->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

        foreach($items  as $item) {
             $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered(); // Amount to add back on
             $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
             /**
              * Here you would load the product and add this amount back on
              */
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

That probably won't work as is, but you get the idea. You need to take care with magento and payment type events, as different payment modules can handle those events slightly differently.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply.
I have actually three websites in my magento installation
So I dont want to change the stock option config, as i need this config for other website.
I would need to programatically stop decreasing qty when order is placed.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can use following:

**config.xml**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
            <observers>
                <inventory>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Vendor_Name_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>revertQuoteInventory</method>
                </inventory>
            </observers>
        </sales_model_service_quote_submit_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function revertQuoteInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $inventory = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/observer');
    $inventory->revertQuoteInventory($observer);
    $inventory->reindexQuoteInventory($observer);

    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(true);
}
```